# Telegraf Influxdb time not match

Tags: influxdb, grafana

im try to figure it out, why my Data form influxdb (sending using telegraf)  date time not match when display to Dashboard usign Grafana, ntp already running and match in any server , client, influxdb and grafana server

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: Some time zone setting or lack thereof?

Comment: cant figure it out when time config in telegraf, but i try query direct in influxdb seemd..data send from telegraf (client server) not match with server..but still cannot find where time config

Comment: I was thinking of a server timezone that by default gets set to somewhere in the US whereas you are in Europe (when I see a 7 hour time diff that's the first thing I check).

Comment: already chek time in all server :
client (telegraf) server  ntp running
grafana & inluxdb server  ntp running

in fact data which sotered in influxdb have diferent time 

so it should be same.

Comment: ntp makes a server run on a reference time, the server's timezone setting decides in what timezone it runs. Can you check `cat /etc/timezone` on the involved servers?

Comment: have a little diferent but it should not problem 
in client telegraf :
[root@ovocollpapp1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock 
ZONE="Asia/Jakarta"
UTC=false


in influxdb & Grafana server :
[root@influxpapp1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="Asia/Jakarta"

Answer (score 0):

solved.... in each dashboard have a setting for TIME LOCAL

thanks all